# Clear the window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a tkinter window in python with some widgets like so:

```
def createWidgets(self):   

    self.grid(padx=25, pady=25)
    self.start = Button(self)
    self.start["text"] = "Start"
    self.start["width"]   = "15"
    self.start["height"]   = "1"
    self.start["command"] =  self.start_g            
    self.start.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, sticky=N)
```

The problem is, I want to remove a widget, so I could add something else to this window. I tried remove() grid_forget() and I can get rid of the widget. Is there any way to remove a widget or wipe the window?

Comment: Does `grid_forget()` not work?

Comment: I might be using it wrong. Adding self.grid_forget(start) says start isn't a global variable, and self.grid_forget(self.start) says im passing 2 arguments.

Comment: Yes you are using it wrong, see my answer for proper usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `grid_forget()` on your widget to permanently remove it.

e.g

```
self.start.grid_forget()
```

If you wanted to clear the whole window then you could do the same on your main `frame`.